# Paint semi-gloss over polyurethane?

Tags: painting, primer, polyurethane

Can I paint (trim work) semi-gloss right over polyurethane without stripping it first? Would it require primer?

Comment: It would probably require a light sanding to give the poly a key so the paint can grip it. Usually poly provides a pretty smooth surface and the paint _may_ stick. For a while...

Comment: be sure to prime first; primers are pretty forgiving these days.

Comment: **No primer on earth can stick to glossy paint**.  Painting over gloss = you want the paint to fail.   The "light sanding" can simply be with a green Scotchbrite pad; the objective is to  remove the gloss. Gloss is a molecularly smooth surface, like Kansas.  A coat of primer or paint needs a molecularly rough surface, like Colorado, to physically lock into.

Comment: Hrm... never thought of Kansas being glossy...